# Smooks Library - EDI message processing failed - expected to contain 2 fields. Actually contains 1 fields

Tags: smooks

### Address_2 is optional but still getting error.

Below is Smook Config for N3 Segment.

```
<medi:segment segcode="N3" xmltag="address-information-stp" > <medi:field xmltag="address_1" /> <medi:field xmltag="address_2" required="false" truncatable="true" /> </medi:segment>
```

Caused by: org.milyn.edisax.EDIParseException: EDI message processing failed [850_DF EDI Message][1.0]. Segment [N3] expected to contain 2 fields. Actually contains 1 fields (not including segment code). Currently at segment number 17.